# In which situations can updating the state without callback cause issues?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

Consider the following code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  function handleClick() {
    setCounter(counter + 1); // update counter without using a callback
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => handleClick()}>
        increase counter
      </button>
      <div>counter is {counter}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am new to React and heard that if a state shall be based on its previous value, I have to use a callback to update the state. For learning purposes I intentionally did exactly the opposite: updating the state without using a callback. I clicked the "increase counter" button multiple times as fast as I could and couldn't notice any issue. It seems to count correct. So:

- Could my sample code lead to clicks not being count, e.g. I click the button 10 times but `counter` ends up only being 9?
- How and why exactly could that happen?

Comment: useCallback is basically just useMemo for functions, it stops the function from being recreated on every rerender. This is mainly useful when you need to use your functions in a reference compare to determine whether or not to rerun logic. For your simple handler there should be no reason to use useCallback, but you could simplify your onClick to avoid the extra anonymous function creation `onClick={handleClick}`. To ensure the current state is always used in your setState call use the function syntax of setState i.e. `setCounter( current => current +1 )`.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to think about it is whether you want it to have closure around the current value of the variable. For example, play around with this:

```js
function handleClick() {
  setCounter(counter + 1);
  setCounter(counter + 1);
}
```

You might expect that to be `2`, but it's `1`! That's because *both* calls will be `setCounter(0 + 1)`. However if you did:

```js
function handleClick() {
  setCounter(c => c + 1);
  setCounter(c => c + 1);
}
```

You indeed get `2`. This is because when each `setCounter` function is run, it calls the callback on the current state (not the value it had closure over).

This is a pretty trivial example, but now consider doing a couple async fetch calls and potentially overwriting one call's state with the other if you don't use a callback!

```js
const [data, setData] = useState({})

useEffect(() => {
  fetch("http://example.resource")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      setData({...data, res})
    });

  fetch("http://another.example.resource")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      setData({...data, res})
    });
}, []);
```

In this example, whichever `fetch` comes back second will clobber the data from the first return because it'll be using a stale `data` reference.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed reply, great examples! I now understand the advantages of using the arrow function. What I don't understand yet: without using the arrow function, is it guaranteed that clicking 10 times leads to the counter being 10 or can there be some kind of race condition, so the counter ends up with only 9?